# The method 'timeZone' was called on null. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use zonedshedule in Flutter local notifications. But exception is returning as null 'timeZone' was called on null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import packages from [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package from pub dev

Now, add those to your dart file as referring to tz:

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
```

Now, make initialize the timeZones:

```
void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  var locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
}
```

Now, you can convert DateTime to TZDateTime for zonedShedule:

```
DateTime time;
tz.TZDateTime selectedDate;

selectedDate =  tz.TZDateTime.from(time, tz.local);
```